# Catch Windows Explorer Events

Tags: windows, explorer, windows-explorer

I would like to write an application that runs next to Windows Explorer. Whenever a user does a selection of a folder or file, I would like to update my program, so the user can make an annotation to the file.

That is all it has to do. The information will be saved per file.

Is it possible to do this without a right-click context menu / (windows shell?)?

Comment: Why don't you write a shell extension rather than a separate app?

Comment: @David I want to catch selection events, so the user doesn't have to right-click and press the correct menu item. We are performing a manual batch and sorting process and this application will help with that. So every extra click is one too many.

Comment: You can write a preview handler shell extension.

Comment: @David "Preview handlers are called when an item is selected to show a lightweight, rich, read-only preview of the file's contents in the view's reading pane". This is what I found on MSDN. It seems that a preview handler is read-only, so how would I pass information to my WinForm with annotations after a preview is clicked. And: It is for ALL file types. Even for folders.

Comment: I thought you could write preview handlers that accepted user input. Perhaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: @David Only keyboard strokes are accepted, but are not recommended. I would just like to pass information to my own Winform that is running as a separate application.

Answer (score 2):

you can use BHO, in the BHO DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE event handler you will get IShellFolderViewDual so you can Find ConnectionPoint of DIID_DShellFolderViewEvents and will recive DISPID_SELECTIONCHANGED event, see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/e558984e-d239-4dc1-b7e0-77041ba7c34e) for detail

Comment: DISPID_SELECTIONCHANGED event never fired now?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) script. Following script will check every 100ms and show a system tooltip with the name of the file/folder selected:

```
Previous=
Current=

Loop
{
    Current :=GetExplorerSel()
    If (Previous <> Current)
    {
        TrayTip, You have selected, %Current%, 10, 1
        Previous = %Current%
    }
    Sleep 100
}

GetExplorerSel(hwnd="") {
    hwnd := hwnd ? hwnd : WinExist("A")
    WinGetClass class, ahk_id %hwnd%
    if (class="CabinetWClass" or class="ExploreWClass")
    for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        if (window.hwnd==hwnd)
        {
            selected := window.Document.SelectedItems
            for item in selected
            ret .= item.path "`n"
            return Trim(ret,"`n")
        }
}
```

If you wish to use another language, just look into *COM* to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a FileSystemWatcher in a Windows Form Project that is triggered when a filesystem change occurs. You can find the FileSystemWatcher in the Toolbox in Visual Studio.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

You can create a watcher for each drive (programmatically) and then ensure that "watch subfolders and subfolder items" is also enabled.